# Windows Explorer Libraries hidden under desktop in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I think I may have accidentally pressed down on Desktop (in the Favourites section of WE) and dragged it down to where Libraries are listed, but whatever happened Libraries are now listed under Desktop in Windows Explorer on my 64 Windows 7 PC and I would like to know how to change this back to the way it was.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on an empty area in the left pane, and click (uncheck) "Show all folders".

Comment: We are looking for more than single sentence answers. Please elaborate on your answer. Citing sources helps validate your claim. More information about [answering](http://superuser.com/help/answering) is available.